# DjangoCMS: login only via https, but server site via http

Tags: security, https, django-cms

I want my DjangoCMS site to be served via http.

But if I login, then https must be used.

I could not find any matching docs.

How to configure DjangoCMS this way?

Comment: why not using only https? it's safer, faster and easier.

Comment: @Tom: Why not use https? Since I don't have a cert. I could install a self-signed cert or a cert from CaCert, but then the browser would should a warning. AFAIK there is no way to avoid the cert warning in the browser without paying a lot of money. I run the DjangoCMS site for a friend. We don't earn money with it.

Comment: letsencrypt.org provide valid certificates for free. The software is still in beta but the certificates are real. (Startssl provide free certificates too but you need pay for revocation if needed)